# how to avoid flickering when changing the source of an mx:Image in flex

Tags: apache-flex, flash, actionscript-3, image, flicker

in my mxml file I have images declared like this:

```
 <mx:Image x="0" y="0" source="assets/bigpicture.png" id="picture1"/>
```

and at some event I do:

picture1.source = "assets/bigpicture2.png";

However this results in flex removing the picture, and when it has loaded it will show it again.

How can I make the mx:image make so that it will continue to show the image until the new image has been loaded?

thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Why don't you just [embed your assets](http://www.google.fr/url?sa=t&source=web&ct=res&cd=1&ved=0CAkQFjAA&url=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.adobe.com%2Fdevnet%2Fflex%2Fquickstart%2Fembedding_assets%2F&ei=29rxStv_M9SMjAfwnvCVAQ&usg=AFQjCNEEGeBZ4fQvQz4utAjLdjDO7B3CsA&sig2=ZuMBl319C6ZPfuNqYPzkfA) in your application if they are always the same ?

If your images must be loaded at runtime:
I think the only way to do it is to load the asset separately from the Image with a Loader, and when the Loader has finished loading, assign it as source of the Image.

Else, you can just fade the Image to alpha=0 before switching the source, and then fade it back to 1.0. It will look smoother, but there will still be no image displayed while the new one is loading.

Comment: embedding is no option since they are huge and there are lots.
Fading is also no option as it has to transition immediately.

Comment: Then loading via a Loader and then setting it into the image is probably your best bet. That's essentially "double buffering" and there's not going to be much faster than that.

Comment: By the way, looks like Flex 4 has an effect for smoothly switching images : http://blog.flexexamples.com/2009/09/21/fading-two-images-using-the-crossfade-effect-in-flex-4/ .

Comment: the link is dead

Comment: well flex is also dead